# Perl: pass implicit variable to custom sub

Tags: perl

In Perl it is possible to implicitly pass the implicit variable to some built in functions, like this:

```
$_ = 'foo';
print; # prints foo
```

Is it possible to define such behavior for my sub? like this:

```
sub bar {
    print $_[0];
}

$_ = 'foo';
&bar; # does not work
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally speaking, doing something like this is not good practice. It is much preferable to just type out the extra two characters: `bar($_)`. Oh, and also, you should use the syntax `bar()`. The other usages `&bar`, `&bar()` have additional hidden functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_[0]` is first element of [`@_`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%40_) array used to get values passed to subroutine. [`$_`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24_) is used as global implicit variable,

```
sub bar {
    my ($arg) = (@_, $_);
    print $arg;
}

local $_ = 'foo';
bar();
bar("explicit foo");
```

Comment: Okay but this is not working like print sub when I pass another argument, like bar('not-a-foo'); Is there some direct way to do it, or do I have to implement it manually (scalar @_ == 0 ? $_ : $_[0]) ?

Comment: @amik check update. This is of course only when function expects only one argument.

Answer (score 1):

Single argument:

```
sub bar {
   my $arg = @_ ? shift : $_;
   ...
}
```

Single argument (5.10+):

```
sub bar(_) {
   my $arg = shift;
   ...
}
```

Multiple arguments:

```
sub bar {
   my @args = @_ ? @_ : $_;
   ...
}
```

Multiple arguments (5.10+):

```
sub bar(_@) {
   my @args = @_;
   ...
}
```